# Angular How convert result API with only value to Object with only one primitive type

Tags: angular

I have many api in backend and  want creat front Angular but how api return only the result ["domain1","domain2"] and  i need to transform this llist String[] to Domain[], with

```js
export interface Domain{
    name:string;
}
```

```js
    this.domainService.getAll().subscribe((data: String[])=>{
      data.forEach((value: String, index: number, array: String[]) => {
        let domain:Domain;
        domain.name = value;
        this.domains.push(domain);
      }
      )    })  
//The variable 'domain' is used before being assigned
```

Comment: Could you give the full error message ? Also, you assign `domain.name` but domain is not assigned to anything yet (you defined its type but it's not an object yet so you'll get an error like "Cannot set properties of undefined"). And you can transform your array more easily with something like : `this.domainService.getAll().subscribe((data: string[]) => {return data.map(domain => { return {name: domain}; })}` (and it'd even be better not to subscibe but to use the map rxjs operator)

Comment: @GuillaumeMMM if im correct you will still need to "subscribe" after map, you need to make observable to work with subscribe or "pipe + take(1)" if im correct

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
export interface Domain{
  name: string;
}

this.domainService.getAll().subscribe((data: string[])=>{
  const mappedDomaing: Domain[] = data.map(x => ({name: x}));
  this.domains.push(...mappedDomaing);
})
```

Changes:

1. data: String[] => data: string[]
2. no need for a loop, you can use something more fancy like `.map`. Less code is better

About your error: //The variable 'domain' is used before being assigned

That is due to.. Really, `domain` needs to be initialized first before you try to access its properties by domain.name.

```
const domain: Domain = {
  name: value // Not sure about value, value is String and name is string, typescript compiler is not happy about that
};
```

Also, Angular is doing great with Observables, you should give them a try, your way of populating domains array is not very good, you can do more with less code with Observables, RxJs and `AsyncPipe`

Answer (score 0):

I change String to string and use that

```js
data.forEach((value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => {
        let domain:Partial<Domain> = {};
        domain.name = value;
        this.domain.push(domain as Domain);
     }
);
```

Comment: That will help but one day it will give you a real headache if you extend that interfacec by 1 additional property, for example, and you will not be able to find all the errors during compile time, app may crash a lot during runtime because it will try to read something from interface that is not really there due to `Partial` and `as` casts